# How to use reflection in Gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, plugins

I need to write a Gradle plugin that will look for an annotation in my application and read marked classes by reflection. I call a method from a Gradle task:

```
private void scanAnnotatedFields() {
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(MisEntity.class));

    for (BeanDefinition beanDefinition : provider.findCandidateComponents("ru.org")) {
        Class clazz = null;
        try {
            clazz = Class.forName(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(clazz.toString());
    }
}
```

But the method read classes in my Gradle plugin application, not from the target application. I think I have to use right classpath or maybe something else. Please help me. Thanks. P. S. Sorry my English.

Comment: Do you have an example to try it out? Probably you just need to set the right classpath.

Comment: Thanks @Opal for your answer. The example may be downloaded from https://yadi.sk/d/o0_YNfZn3JFiZh. There are 3 projects. 1st is my application. Annotation is the library with an annotation. And mis-template-plugin is the plugin. There is absolute path to project 1 in the file BuildLogicFunctionalTest.java. While I was preparing the example I cought an exception ClassNotFoundException. Plugin don't see MisEntity3.class at runtime. If you help me, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic is answer on my question. But instead of Spring reflections I used org.reflections.
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-plugin-with-reflections/22690/7